# WordPress contact form 7 function

Tags: php, wordpress

I want a form that functions like the contact form function on this website in WordPress anyone tell me how can I do this please help?

Website link: https://arizona-auto-parts.autopartsearch.com/

I want this same website contact form on my WordPress website like a filter.

[image: I want same this website contact form on my wordpress website like a filter]

Answer (score 1):

To install contact form 7 on your wordpress site use this plugin [page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/),

To install the plugin you can do it manually or you can login to your Wordpress site,

1. click plugins.
2. click add new.
3. search for contact form 7.
4. click install

At this point you can go into the contact form 7 plugin and create a new form. Then use the shortcode it provides you to add the form anywhere you want on your wordpress site.